# Intuition for the questions?

Tags: algorithm

A [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/contest/weekly-contest-130/problems/number-of-enclaves/) is as follows:

> Given a 2D array A, each cell is 0 (representing sea) or 1 (representing land). A move consists of walking from one land square 4-directionally to another land square, or off the boundary of the grid. Return the number of land squares in the grid for which we cannot walk off the boundary of the grid in any number of moves.  For the input `[[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,0,0]]`, the output should be `3`.
>
> -> The solution is a simple DFS starting with the 1s, but the 'ahaa' moment is to start from the boundaries first (otherwise we get lot of Time Limit Exceeds because of the number of 1s)

---

[Another question](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-components/) is as follows:

> We are given head, the head node of a linked list containing unique integer values. We are also given the list G, a subset of the values in the linked list. Return the number of connected components in G, where two values are connected if they appear consecutively in the linked list.  For the input `head: 0->1->2->3` and `G = [0, 1, 3]`, the output is `2`.
>
> -> This again is trivial to solve, once you figure out the trick of [counting the last node of the component](https://leetcode.com/problems/linked-list-components/discuss/123842/C++JavaPython-Easy-and-Concise-Solution-with-Explanation).

---

While I believe I am in a position to solve general algorithm questions like DFS, BFS, etc. I fail to recognize such 'ahaa's, despite practicing for about 2 years.  Are there any resources that you would suggest that would help me identify and recognize them better?  My apologies if this is out of context for SO; but given the length of the question and the audience, SO is my best hope.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any "Aha!" moment in the first question: Unless you have left out important parts of the problem description, there are inputs that force a program to examine the entire board whether or not you start at the edges (e.g. a board consisting of all 1s), so starting at the edges doesn't help.  For the second question, I don't see how it could be solved in another way, other than building an explicit graph representation.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, for the first question, if you start from the boundaries, you can just use Flood Fill technique.  In the 2nd one, you work in the reverse - just find that 2 is not present in the set `G`, so there are two connected components.  (`0->1` and just `3`).

Comment: In my mind, flood fill is essentially the same as BFS -- in what way are they different?  They both need to examine every position exactly once.  Also, flood fill will take the same amount of time regardless of where you start it in the all-ones case.

Comment: @J. Doe Imagine spiral of 1s with many rolls and separate 1 in the center. Scanning from boundaries or from anothe place takes the same time - you have to traverse all spiral length.